# how to use call back function in viewdidload()?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, callback

i was given a class(Client) with a function(requestSitesData) which can get data from server, and it has @escaping in it:

```
func requestSitesData(response: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomTimeDelay()) {
            guard self.isRequestSuccessful() else {
                response(nil, ClientError.requestFailed)

                return
            }
            guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.responseFilename, withExtension: "json") else {
                response(nil, ClientError.noFile)
                return 
            }
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                response(data, nil)
            } catch let error {
                response(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

so I think the response function is a callback function here. In my project, i have a global variable to store the data from server, and wanna display it on my viewcontroller. But it seems like no matter where I put the call_back function in the viewcontroller class, the callback function is called after all the functions(as it should be), so I can't get data in viewdidload().

```
func call_back(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void {
        print("call_back called")
        if let file_data = data {
            if let sites_map = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: file_data, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: [Dictionary<String, Any>]] {
                if let sites = sites_map["sites"] {
                    for site in sites {
                        if let name = site["name"] as? String,
                        let slogan = site["slogan"] as? String,
                        let url = site["url"] as? String,
                        let description = site["description"] as? String,
                        let color = site["color"] as? String {
                            let single_site: Site = Site(name: name, slogan: slogan, url: url, description: description, color: color)
                            sites_res.append(single_site)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let c = Client()
        c.requestSitesData { (response_data, response_error) in
            self.call_back(data: response_data, error: response_error)
            print("ddd")
        }

    }
```

i don't know how to get data in viewdidload(), is it because the way I call this call_back function is wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need the data in `viewDidLoad()`?  The nature of a callback is that you don't know how long it will take to be called.

Comment: because i need display the data in this view. But i can not change anything in Client class as required.

Comment: When you get the callback, use that data to update the view.  While you are waiting on the data to come back, you could display a spinner to let the user know that data is coming.

Comment: Then I guess I need to reload the view in ViewWillAppear? how can I know when the callback return?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reload update the data of the view inside the callback, the escaping closures outlives the function it was called in so the callback inside it will only happen after the function finishes executing and returns the expected value to the callback.

The problem is you don't know how long it will take to return that data, you either create a function to update to reload the view and make the callback function call it or you can fetch the data before you open you present the ViewController and pass the data to it.

**EDIT 1**

Try doing in the way shown below, so that it updates your data in the View Controller or just the data in the View, but change it to correspond to your needs.

```
func call_back(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void {
    print("call_back called")
    if let file_data = data {
        if let sites_map = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: file_data, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: [Dictionary<String, Any>]] {
            if let sites = sites_map["sites"] {
                for site in sites {
                    if let name = site["name"] as? String,
                    let slogan = site["slogan"] as? String,
                    let url = site["url"] as? String,
                    let description = site["description"] as? String,
                    let color = site["color"] as? String {
                        let single_site: Site = Site(name: name, slogan: slogan, url: url, description: description, color: color)
                        sites_res.append(single_site)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let c = Client()
    c.requestSitesData { (response_data, response_error) in
        self.call_back(data: response_data, error: response_error)
        updateData()
    }

}

func updateData(){
//either update your data here or just update the data in the subviews.
    mylabel.text = data.text
}
```

Comment: How can I reload the view and call viewdidload again? I tried add "self.loadView()" in callback but it report erros.

Comment: loadView() is part of the ViewController lifecycle, it's not recommended to call it again, just reload the data and update the subviews in the view. It's pretty normal to update the view data and update its subviews to show the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

Modify function as below :

```
func call_back(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> [String: [Dictionary<String, Any>]]? {
            print("call_back called")
            if let file_data = data {
                if let sites_map = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: file_data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: [Dictionary<String, Any>]] {
                    return sites_map
                }
            }
            return nil
        }


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let c = Client()
        c.requestSitesData { (response_data, response_error) in
            if let sites_map = self.call_back(data: response_data, error: response_error){
        if let sites = sites_map["sites"] {
            for site in sites {
                if let name = site["name"] as? String,
                    let slogan = site["slogan"] as? String,
                    let url = site["url"] as? String,
                    let description = site["description"] as? String,
                    let color = site["color"] as? String {
                    let single_site: Site = Site(name: name, slogan: slogan, url: url, description: description, color: color)
                    sites_res.append(single_site)
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: smart solution. But the return type is Void, which I can't change as required.

Comment: what issue with change the return type?